# TypeScript iterate over string enum with the enum type instead of string type

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a string enum in TypeScript, and I want to iterate over it like below. However, when I do this the type of the iterator is a string instead of the enum type.

```
enum Enum { A = 'a', B = 'b' };

let cipher: { [key in Enum]: string };

for (const letter in Enum) {
    cipher[letter] = 'test'; // error: letter is of type 'string' but needs to be 'Enum'
}
```

The exact error I get is this:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: string; b: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: string; b: string; }'.ts(7053)
```

This seems strange as it's guaranteed the letter is an Enum. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I don't think my explanation is perfect so I'm posting this as a comment.
`cipher` will have the keys as the `Enum` values, that is `{ a: string, b: string }` because you are using a string enum, but when you are iterating with the `for ... in` you are iterating over the enumerable props of the generated object that is `['A', 'B']` because the object is generated as `var Enum;
(function (Enum) {
    Enum["A"] = "a";
    Enum["B"] = "b";
})(Enum || (Enum = {}));`

Comment: so A workaround would be to iterate over the values of the object with the `for ... of` and `Object.values`
because the Enum is not directly iterable.
final code:
`for (const letter of Object.values(Enum)) {
    cipher[letter] = 'test'; // error: letter is of type 'string' but needs to be 'Enum'
}`

Comment: @robertgr991 that works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post my comments as an answer so the questions won't remain unanswered.

The type of `cipher` will have the keys as the values of `Enum`, that is:

```ts
let cipher: {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

because you are using a string enum. But when iterating with `for...in` you iterate over the enumerable properties of the generated object, those properties are `['A', 'B']` because the generated object(TypeScript v4) would be:

```js
var Enum;
(function (Enum) {
    Enum["A"] = "a";
    Enum["B"] = "b";
})(Enum || (Enum = {}));
```

So you need to iterate over the enum values.
For this you can use `Object.values` to get an array of it's values and `for...of` to iterate over it. This way, `letter` type will be `Enum`.

```js
for (const letter of Object.values(Enum)) {
    cipher[letter] = 'test'; // error: letter is of type 'string' but needs to be 'Enum'
}
```

I never used `for...in` with an enum before but I would have expected the compiler to have enough information so the `for...in` strictly types `letter` to a union of `"A" | "B"` but it seems that it widens the type to `string`.